# Branching in Power Apps Form to Hide or Show Fields Based on Any Dropdown Value

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapps-forms, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-portal

In Power Apps, I have created a Form. In one of the DataCards (**DataCardValue10**), the Form asks a question where the user can *select multiple values* from a drop down list. The values in **DataCardValue10** are:

- Not Applicable
- Consumer
- Employee
- Government

As a result, I have three different fields that are not supposed to show, until one or more values are selected. These fields are:

- ConsumerDataCard1
- EmployeeDataCard1
- GovernmentDataCard1

What do I need to write into the **Visible** property for each *DataCard1* so that if the user selects any combination of the values, the appropriate DataCard fields display, so they can make selections?

I looked up using the **IF** and **SWITCH** statements in Power Apps, but I cannot get this to work? Please let me know if you need pictures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your DataCardValue10 is a multi-select combo box, you can put the below formula for each of your other data cards.

Use the below formula for the Visible property of ConsumerDataCard1:

```
If("Consumer" in DataCardValue10.SelectedItems.Value,true,false)
```

Use the below formula for the Visible property of EmployeeDataCard1:

```
If("Employee" in DataCardValue10.SelectedItems.Value,true,false)
```

The same goes for the GovernmentDataCard1.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much @Dhruvil Prajapati. It worked!!